# set background image dimensions IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an image bigger then a normal iPhone screen that I want to set as my background image but when I load the simulator I just see part of the image. Here is how I assigned the image:

```
UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:background]];
```

how can I set the background image to something like self.view.bounds? If I was to use a UIImageView how do I ensure that it is in the background!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a UIImageView, give the UIImage to the UIImageView and add the UIImageView as a child to the view. Like so:

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name.png"]];
[backgroundView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view insertSubView:backgroundView atIndex:0];
[backgroundView release];
```

Comment: I have other images that this is over shadowed by. How can I make this one be in the background instead of laying on everything.

Comment: by using `[self.view insertSubView:backgroundView atIndex:0]` instead of `addSubview`.

Answer (score 0):

Set uiimageview frame - this is limitations for display.

Use

```
 background.frame = CGRectMake (0,0, 320, 480); // as example - full screen,
```

also like in post above add addSubview and release code.

If you used frame - coordinates calculate from your superview - in that case - from self.view (simulator display). If you used bounds, coordinates calculate relatively to yours  uiimageview (not self.view)